# Play framework 1.7 puts compiled templates in root dir

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I just moved an application to a new server and upgraded from Play! version 1.6 to 1.7.

In the app directory, when templates are compiled (precompiling or running), I get a lot of strange files like these, in the root dir:

```
'Template_1159$_run_closure1$_closure2.class'
'Template_1159$_run_closure1.class'
 Template_1159.class
'Template_1160$_run_closure1$_closure2.class'
'Template_1160$_run_closure1.class'
 Template_1160.class
'Template_1161$_run_closure1$_closure2.class'
'Template_1161$_run_closure1.class'
 Template_1161.class
```

I would expect such files to be deep under the "tmp" or "precompiled" folder, or such. Did anything change?

I also think that "Precompiling" was shown in the console on the earlier version, and it is not now. Not sure about this, but perhaps it could be a symptom somehow?

And help appreciated! Also please indicate if there is a better place to ask such questions.

Edit: Clarified that it is not only during precompiling.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that this was a regression in 1.7.0:

https://github.com/playframework/play1/issues/1403